# show picture file on pi3b

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, raspbian

I'm trying to show a picture file (in this example icon.png) on the screen using dispmanx (bcm_host.h) and OpenCV.

the code im using:

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2012, Broadcom Europe Ltd
All rights reserved.
Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    * Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the
      names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
      derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
(INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

#include "bcm_host.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#ifndef ALIGN_UP 
#define ALIGN_UP(x,y) ((x + (y)-1) & ~((y)-1)) 
#endif

class Rect {
    static int rectCount;
    static DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T   display;
    static DISPMANX_MODEINFO_T         info;
    static DISPMANX_RESOURCE_HANDLE_T  resource;
    void                              *image;
    static DISPMANX_UPDATE_HANDLE_T    update;
    DISPMANX_ELEMENT_HANDLE_T          element;
    uint32_t                           vc_image_ptr;
    VC_RECT_T       src_rect;
    VC_RECT_T       dst_rect;
    VC_DISPMANX_ALPHA_T alpha;
    int x, y;
    int width, height;
    int pitch;
    int aligned_height;
    VC_IMAGE_TYPE_T type;

public:
    Rect(int x, int y, int width, int height, unsigned char* data):x(x),y(y),width(width),height(height) {
        if(display == 0) {
            bcm_host_init();
            display = vc_dispmanx_display_open(1);
            int ret = vc_dispmanx_display_get_info(display, &info);
            assert(ret == 0); 
            std::cout << "Display:  " << info.width << " x " << info.height << std::endl;
        }   
//        pitch = ALIGN_UP(width*2, 32);
        pitch = ALIGN_UP(width*3, 32);
        aligned_height = ALIGN_UP(height, 16);
//        type = VC_IMAGE_RGB565;
//        type = VC_IMAGE_BGRX8888;
        type = VC_IMAGE_BGR888;
//        image = calloc(1, pitch * height);

    image=data;

    assert(image);

   }

    int getCount() { return rectCount; }

    void beforeDraw() {
        resource = vc_dispmanx_resource_create(type,
                                               width,
                                               height,
                                               &vc_image_ptr);
        assert(resource);
        update = vc_dispmanx_update_start(0);
        assert(update);
    }

    void draw(int layer) {
        VC_DISPMANX_ALPHA_T alpha = {
                        DISPMANX_FLAGS_ALPHA_FROM_SOURCE,
                        120, /*alpha 0->255*/
                        0
        };

        vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&dst_rect, 0, 0, width, height);
        int ret = vc_dispmanx_resource_write_data(resource,
                      type,
                      pitch,
                      image,
                      &dst_rect);
        assert(ret == 0);

        vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&src_rect, 0, 0, width << 16, height << 16);

        vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&dst_rect, x, y, width, height);

        element = vc_dispmanx_element_add(update,
                      display,
                      layer,        // layer
                      &dst_rect,
                      resource,
                      &src_rect,
                      DISPMANX_PROTECTION_NONE,
                      &alpha,
                      NULL,        // clamp
                      DISPMANX_NO_ROTATE);
    }

    void afterDraw() {
        int ret = vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync(update);
        assert(ret == 0);
    }

    ~Rect() {
        update = vc_dispmanx_update_start(0);
        assert(update);
        int ret = vc_dispmanx_element_remove(update, element);
        assert(ret == 0);
        ret = vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync(update);
        assert(ret == 0);
        rectCount--;
        if(rectCount == 0) {
            std::cout << "No more rectangles" << std::endl;
            ret = vc_dispmanx_resource_delete(resource);
            assert(ret == 0);
            ret = vc_dispmanx_display_close(display);
            assert(ret == 0);
            display = 0;
        }
    }

};

DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T Rect::display = 0;
int Rect::rectCount = 0;
DISPMANX_MODEINFO_T Rect::info;
DISPMANX_RESOURCE_HANDLE_T Rect::resource;
DISPMANX_UPDATE_HANDLE_T Rect::update;

int main(void)
{

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Rect>> rects;

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/home/pi/myDispmanx/t.png" , cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
//    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/home/pi/myDispmanx/t.png" , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);


    int width = img.size().width;
    int height = img.size().height;
    int i=0;

    std::cout << "image width:  " << width << std::endl;
    std::cout << "image height:  " << height << std::endl;


    std::shared_ptr<Rect> r = std::make_shared<Rect>(0, 0, width, height, img.data);

    r->beforeDraw();

    r->draw(i+5);

    rects.push_back(r);

    rects[0]->afterDraw();

    sleep(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running the code above on a pi3b (Raspbian os).
The code is error free on compilation(using g++).

however when I run the code in some cases I get "segmentation error" or  double free or corruption (out): 0x01a2f480 (<===probably some memory address)

these errors change from one to another when I change the .png file.
(still couldn't manage to figure out the reason of each case)

with a little knowledge I have on programming I believe I should be getting the same result no matter which .png file i'm using?
can anybody elaborate?

P.S I must add in one case I had a very blurry picture as an output.

EDIT: Code updated, got rid of the errors but still getting a distorted projection of the picture in some occasions. e.g: [cat.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aPUV.png)
Notice: the width and height are set considering the dimensions of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to go through such a big code, it is better to write a small sample where your error occur, to give expected behaviour and some sample images that show the problem (I mean like the blurry one not the error) . My recommendation is to use a debugger and check the output of different parts of your code to see if you get what you are expecting.

I could spot one error though:

```
image = calloc(1, pitch * height);

image=data;
```

This will allocate the data and put in image such pointer. Then you replace your pointer with the pointer to the data of OpenCV. Then you do:

```
free(image);
```

but this pointer points to the data of the cv::Mat that will try to delete it later on, so it will have double free error. To copy the data of a pointer use something like [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)

Comment: thank you very much, I will make the question more efficient as I progress, are you suggesting that I do not need the calloc() and the free() lanes?

Comment: memcpy copies the data to one place to another, both data should be allocated, however, calloc and free are more from C. In C++ new and delete are used. `auto a = new uchar[n];` for example and then `delete [] a;` or you can pass the cv::Mat and use its data directly... just remember who owns the data and who has to delete it.